# Get string from EditText not working, returning empty string

Tags: java, android

In a android studio project i need to get user input in edittext. here is my code
**Xml file**

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/amount"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp" />
```

**in .java file**

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    EditText amount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount);
    String amount_text =amount.getText().toString();

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(betNow.this,amount_text ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Everytime it returns empty `Toast`

Comment: is your xml file set for this activity?

Answer (score 2):

You need to Retrieve your `amount_text` from `EditText`  inside **`onClick(View v)`** like below code

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText amount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount);
            String amount_text = amount.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(betNow.this, amount_text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I get it.... Its not worked earlier because I tried to get value earlier before user click the button, now I change the code like this

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    final EditText amount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount);

    final String amount_text =amount.getText().toString();
 Toast.makeText(betNow.this,amount_text ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    }
});
```

Its working fine

Answer (score 1):

Don't initialize editText in onClick()

```
EditText amount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount);


button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        String amount_text =amount.getText().toString();
 Toast.makeText(betNow.this,amount_text ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Find EditText outside of onClickListener

```
 EditText amount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount);

  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        String amount_text =amount.getText().toString();





        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
 Toast.makeText(betNow.this,amount_text ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue occurs when you put getText outside of onClick. 
You should put `String amount_text = amount.getText().toString();`
in `onClick` and try again.